# ¿PopUp en Movimiento con JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Me Gustaría Mover un PopUp con JavaScript, La Verdad soy Nuevo en Esto y no se Cómo Hacerlo, y no he encontrado una Respuesta Clara por Internet...

```js
window.open("https://es.stackoverflow.com/", "VentanadeEjemplosinFuncion", "width=200,height=200");
```

Comment: A qué te refieres con mover?

Comment: @VickMuñoz Algo como Esto pero no con Fines "Maliciosos" : https://youtu.be/GF5bR6GE2rk?t=24 (Baja el Volumen) Intente Conseguir el Código Fuente de este Joke pero no lo Logré...

Answer (score 0):

Eso es algo muy sencillo, para mover una ventana primero la creas pero que no se te olvide asignarla a algo:

```
const ventana = window.open('', '', 'width=200, height=200');
```

ahora solo tienes que moverla con la funcion moveTo que tiene el objeto window:

```
//Esto movera la ventana a la pocision 500 en x y 500 en y
ventana.moveTo(500, 500);
```

Ahora bien, si lo que quieres es que la ventana se este constantemente moviendo puedes usar un setInterval, que te permite ejecutar una funcion cada cierto tiempo:

```
let ultimoMovX = 0;

function moverVentanaA(ventana, posX, posY){

    ventana.moveTo(posX, posY);
    ventana.focus();

}

const intervaloMover = setInterval(()=>{

    if(ventana.x >= 0 && ventana.x + ventana.outerWidth < screen.width){

       moverVentanaA(ventana, ultimoMovX, 500);
       ultimoMovX++;
    }else{
       ultimoMovX = 0;
    }

},1);
```

Comment: Esto aplicaria de manera para por ejemplo solo movimiento en X, pero si quieres moverte en Y, tambien puedes hacerlo con ese codigo, lo unico es que tendrias que agregar otra variable que maneje la Y y tambien dependiendo de como quieres que se mueva tu ventana, para el caso de algo como lo del video, tendrias que usar las funciones seno y coseno, donde el rango maximo de estas es 1.

Comment: Tengo una Duda si Quiero usar la Primera opción (nombrevariable.moveTo) ¿Como puedo hacer que en una posición Tome un Numero aleatorio, por Ejemplo entre 100 y 500?

Comment: Para ello usa Math.random(); que te devuelve un numero entre 0 inclusivo y 1 exclusivo,  de manera aleatoria,  luego este numero lo puedes multiplicar para que obtengas tu numero deseado entre un rango. En W3Schools muestran bien como hacer que el rango de Math.random sea entre un numero diferente de 0 y 1, con una operación matematica realmente sencilla.